# What happen if UDP server is down

Tags: udp, udpclient

Not sure if the question is being asked before, I could not find one.

But my question is ..

What happens on client side when UDP server goes down unacceptably.

Does the message get queued up in client Kernel buffer.

If yes,what happen after the buffer is fill does it flushes the buffer after it fill.

To me it looks like it does but just want to confirm and in case it doesnt ...

What possible effect it has on the client machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the UDP server process goes down the socket gets closed by the server. This also means that no data get queued up because without socket you have no socket buffer for queuing. The result is that the data simply get lost.